# How to sync complex domain objects structure between server and client

Tags: wcf, domain-driven-design, client-server, prism

Are there any best practices for syncing hierarchical domain objects between client with modular structure (WPF,PRISM,MVVM) and server(WCF service and NHibernate for persistence in DB)?

Already have DTO objects for transport and separate module for server requests with callback management infrastructure.

Thanks in advance=)
Alexey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx).

Although its main implementation seems to focus on ADO.NET and synchronization of relational data, the Sync Framework supports synchronization of any type of object, including your own custom objects.

You can also choose the protocol over which you want to synchronize, so if you'd like to use e.g. WCF, it will work too.

It does, however, require some work or your behalf.

Comment: Interesting thing. Can it handle realtime replication? for example another user changed something on server and all other joined users will se it immediatly? Or user creates device, request is sent to server, if everything is ok, response message is sent to client that it is ok and operation is successful? Lots of info on framework and reading docs atm=) Thanks=)

Comment: Synchronization is initiated by a client, but can go both ways. If you set up the client so that it synchronizes very often, you may get close to an illusion of what you are asking for, but possibly at the cost of high network traffic.